# Is this a usable pattern? (Enterprise application UI)

Tags: tables, enterprise

I'm working on an application that requires a user to assign a year or two to a list of users (there are two year options available. One user can be assigned to one or both years.) And one user per year can be assigned a Leader status. I'm redesigning the current capability, which had a bunch of columns of checkboxes and radio buttons to assign. This also meant the user had to assign years for each row of users and not do any batch assigning. I'm wondering if the pattern I came up with makes a lick of sense, or if there's some other pattern that would work better?

I'm including a quick mockup, but won't provide the instructions because I want to see how intuitive (or not) this is.

(Data and design has been changed from original, but intended interaction remains the same.) 
[image]

Comment: Hi, to clarify. Is the UI above the table used to filter the table? Or is that a separate UI to assign these attributes to a user in the table results? I think I'm confused because the mockup shows results in the table, but there are no options selected in the UI above. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi, you got it right in your second question. It's to assign attributes to a user(s) in the table results. Some of them might already have attributes assigned from when they were uploaded or added manually. This page is specifically for assigning, and those assignments can be edited here, or removed altogether.

Comment: @MRL if the top set are actions they should be buttons rather than checkboxes

Comment: It's not immediately obvious what an admin would need to do to change any of the information. The controls above the list look like filters for changing the content of the list rather than tools for editing entries. You may need to keep these two operations separate: show the list with checkboxes and then allow the admin to open a row (or multiple rows and then present the edit controls.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have more space in the user name column. You can add a badge for leader and make a tooltip for in which year they become a leader.

The second option is you can put the same design as it is, just add leader badge and put a tooltip for years.

Thank you

Comment: We try to refrain from using tooltips to convey pertinent information. Also, it's possible for a user to be leader both years.

Comment: Also, do an A/B testing or use some recording tool for examining user experience, So you will get to exact pain point of the user.

Comment: I agree with @MRL here. Tooltips have low discoverability and should not be used to carry critical information.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a "dual-list" kind of approach (ie user moves items from one box to another).

- Since there are not much meta-data to be shown, table view might be excessive/unnecessary
- Having four columns/boxes makes it easier to read

Just an idea :)

[image: quick wireframe]